# HTML/CSS display=table-row alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting two components to align in using the `<div display='table-cell'>`. The first component is being displayed with a gap at the top. I want them to be displayed so that they are aligned.

Here's the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66s7x5fr/

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group modifierColumn">
    <div class="cell">
        <select class="form-control input-sm btn-primary">
            <option value="Broad">Broad</option>
            <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"> 
        <span class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button> 
            </span> 
            <input class="form-control text-justify" type="text" value="0"> </input>
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button> 
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the **CSS**:

```
.modifierColumn .cell:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center horizontal table-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226625/how-to-center-horizontal-table-cell)

Comment: Vertically align the `.cell`s : http://jsfiddle.net/66s7x5fr/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.cell {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Somewhat obscure rule. Baffles many. Check [Understanding vertical align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to nocarrier's response:

```
.cell {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the the top-padding that the class cell has. Try to use a col-md-x to be more responsive.

```
<div class="form-group modifierColumn" tabindex="0">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control input-sm btn-primary">
            <option value="Broad">Broad</option>
            <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"> 
        <span class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button> 
            </span> 
            <input class="form-control text-justify" type="text" value="0"> </input>
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button> 
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no padding on the cell class - at least that I've declared. Can you explain further?

Comment: If you inspect the element cell with google chrome its seens there is a top-padding beacause the vertical-align. For that reason I recommend to use col-md-x like in the example.