# How to center horizontal table-cell and content inside it in the middle

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am building on the question originally asked here [How to center horizontal table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226625/how-to-center-horizontal-table-cell) with a slight modification.

Basically, DIVs need to be centered as they are now, however, I also need to vertically align all the content in the cell in the middle.

Changing `vertical-align: middle;` for `.column` does NOTHING. If I change `display: inline-block;` for `.column` to `display: table-cell`, it will align content in the middle, but then `.column` DIVs are no longer centered and widths are all broken (currently all a evenly set to 25%). Setting  `margin:auto;` or text-align on parent does nothing.

I've been running around this for days. Your help is appreciated.

```css
/* Setting the container to be a table with maximum width and height */
#container {
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
/* All sections (container's children) should be table rows with minimal height */

.section {
 display: table-row;
 min-height: 1px;
}

/* We need one extra container, setting it to full width */
.columns-container {
 display: table-cell;
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
/* Creating columns */
.column {
    display: inline-block; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 min-height: 150px;
 width: 25%;
 text-align: left;
}
#a {
 background-color: pink;
}
#b {
 background-color: lightgreen;
}
#c {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="columns-container">
      <div class="column" id="a"> Contents A </div>
      <div class="column" id="b"> Contents B </div>
      <div class="column" id="c"> Contents C </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the follows, it uses CSS3 Transforms, see the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) details. And be aware of the [white spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) thing on inline block.

**[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fy7mcu7w/)**

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.column > div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#a { background-color: pink; }
#b { background-color: lightgreen; }
#c { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column" id="a"><div>Contents A</div></div>
    <div class="column" id="b"><div>Contents B</div></div>
    <div class="column" id="c"><div>Contents C</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. That looks like it may be one of the ways. Then just wrap the whole #container into a wrapper with text-align:center.

Comment: @FL did I make it all clear, and you have any other concerns? or you want something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/f7f0v69d/

Comment: When the table is viewed in a mobile device (screen width 320px), the entire table stays fixed width and doesn't "wrap" unless I add  float: left; to .column. But as soon as I add   float: left;, the content is no longer in the middle.

Comment: Check out jsfiddle.net/magic565/39ebehp2 I had to add float:left to .column (that's only for narrow screens) so that cells stack vs. stay fixed on one line (and therefore don't fit). In this case, the content inside the cells is no longer in the middle.

Comment: @FL alright, I think this must be it, see the updated answer, demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fy7mcu7w/ please make it all clear in the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

setting your `.column`'s `line-height` to the `height` of the element is step one; so: `line-height:150px` vertically aligns the content.
Then, simply edit the `text-align:left` style declaration you have set on `.column` to `text-align:center` finishes the vertically alignment in this case.
here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/t2xgL3rm/